# Can I host the API on Firebase Hosting?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-hosting

I created an API using PHP and linked it with MySQL for the android app. (There is no front-end)

Is it possible to upload the files and database to Firebase Hosting or does it support only static websites?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can package your PHP based API in a container image you will be able to deploy it using Cloud Run and, by using Firebase Hosting, you can direct HTTPS requests to trigger your containerized API to run.

More details in the [Firebase Hosting doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/serverless-overview).